# Taking a telephone number from the address book

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

If the user taps on a button, the address book should open.
Then the user should choose a contact. The telephone number of the contact should be displayed in the app.

How can I realize this?

Comment: google on using ContactsContracts action pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that instead of opening the contacts application you instead query the ContactsContract.Contacts content provider to get cursor with the list of contacts and display this list in your application. When an item is selected from the resulting view you can easily extract the number and display it.